# « ne pas *infinitif* » mais pas avec « point » ?

Tags: grammaire, négation, infinitif

On m'a toujours dit d'ajouter les mots « ne » et « pas, rien, jamais » avant l'infinitif, par exemple :

> Il est important de ne jamais oublier de mettre les mots négatifs avant l'infinitif !

Cependant, j'ai lu récemment la phrase suivante qui m'a fait réfléchir :

> il s’obstina à ne vouloir point demander pardon au Roi

J'aurais pensé que « point » se serait placé devant « vouloir », mais apparemment, ce n'est pas le cas, ce qui mène à la question : pourquoi ? Est-ce que je me trompe sur la règle en général ? Ou est-ce qu'il y a une exception quand il s'agit de « point » ?

Merci.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C'est une tournure ancienne qui peut encore subsister dans des textes littéraires. On peut aussi la trouver avec *pas* :

> *Voilà ce que c'est de ne vouloir pas qu'on démontre !*

Diderot, *Jacques le fataliste et son maître*, 1785

Comment: En effet je l'avais lu dans un livre qui citait un autre extrait très ancien, donc voilà, merci.